# Left align text AND right align image in CSS

Tags: css, html, layout

I am somewhat new to CSS and I have a problem that I can't seem to solve.  I would like to have a series of divs on my page (stacked one on top of the other) and each of them should contain some text, and one or more images.

In particular, I would like the text to be left aligned, and vertically aligned in the middle, and the images should be right aligned, and the height of the div should be based upon the height of the images (which can be variable).

Basically each of the divs should look like so:
[image]

So far I have been able to get one or more of the requirements listed above, but never all of them at the same time.  Is this actually possible with pure CSS, or should I just quit wasting my time and use a table?

Comment: Post your HTML and text please. With 4K+ rep you should know by now what we'll need.

Comment: I don't have any HTML per se.  It is quite literally one block of text, and two images.  I have tried bunches of combinations to no avail, so I don't see how posting one of them would help anything.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Y6ak3/

Comment: If the height is based on the image then you will have some difficulty with that. If you switch the image with the text then your life would be much easier. I'm not saying this isn't impossible so give me a few an ill try something's out!

Comment: @JoshC No, the images should determine the height.  In your example, if the images are taller than 50px, the float will screw everything up. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/9vb7m/

Comment: @A.R. JoshC gave you the code, all you have to do is modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Alright I have a final solution that will work but depends on you if it's the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i have a solution for you chek this link http://jsfiddle.net/8mQc4/15/.

It's based use some properties like:

```
float and vertical-align.
```

This code allows flexible height and width of img, and also his container center vertically de text.Just try with more large texts or images.

Comment: It would be nice to know why this got downvoted. It is the only one that actually works.

Comment: I really don't know why someone downvoted this maybe it's because some people don't appreciate the use of float :P

Comment: who knows.  Maybe because there is mention of tables in it, even though <table> is probably the only thing that works exactly right.

Comment: This is close enough.  If the image heights aren't the same it gets a bit wonky, but in my case all of my images are the same height so that is OK with me.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man I got a fun solution for you that may work but none the less is a solid idea!

If you set the image as the background you can avoid floating or positioning.

```
.section {
   background: url(http://jpowell43.mydevryportfolio.com/flatDesign/images/tab-2.svg) no-repeat rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4);
   background-position: center right;
   background-size: contain;
   width: 100%;
}
```

The only thing that I may find to be a problem is the image size is based on the content inside of the div.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/dcpJ2/1/)

This will allow the image to have a fixed size but! it does run into the problem of relying on the text for size over the image. :/

```
background-size: 80px 60px;
```

[Fixed size](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/dcpJ2/2/)

With the use of `min-height: whatever;` You can still achieve the desired result but not 100% the best.

[min-height](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/dcpJ2/4/)

Comment: What if you want the `img` to have fixed dimensions?

Comment: Yeah I just ran into that problem so let me see if there is a way to achieve this otherwise I can remove the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say remove the answer, it is still useful nonetheless.

Comment: Alright i will leave it up! sadly it isn't the best answer but it is a solution to someone I would suppose.