# CSS to align label and inputs on form

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a problem with aligning my labels and input fields in a form.  Time and again I end up with something like this:

[image]

Which is produced with HTML like so:

```
...
<ul>
    <li>
      <label for="STREET">Street</label>
      <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Street field is required." id="STREET" name="STREET" type="text" value="P.O. Box 1053" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="SUITE">Suite</label>
      <input id="SUITE" name="SUITE" type="text" value="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="city">City</label>
      <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The City field is required." id="city" name="city" type="text" value="Dalton" />
    </li>
...
```

Naturally my issue is that the labels and the inputs don't line up, so the display is all jaggy, etc.  I can personally think of many ways around this, using a table, setting a bunch of divs, and picking widths, etc. so that everything lines up properly.

It's not that these approaches don't work, but they don't seem to be more of a hack than a real solution, and then I end up having to manipulate the label widths if the label text / font changes, etc.

Is there an easier way to solve this type of problem, while preserving simple HTML / CSS or should I stick with the classic approach of hard coding widths, divs, using tables, etc ?

Comment: I will probably be stoned for this, but I'd use table. Not really a hack and pretty easy to maintain.

Comment: Table is one way, setting min-width on the labels or float the inputs to the right are some others.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I am with you.  The CSS crowd always complains about tables, but rarely offer anything that works as consistently and predictably.

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, which you have here: a column of headings (<th>) and a column of data.

Comment: What about having the labels above the input elements? Good article on what to shoot for: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-white-space/

Comment: @RogerPate Tables are for fixing the vast shortcomings of CSS as well as tabular data.

Comment: @A.R. You can easily do this with CSS + markup without using tables.  Yes, tables can be an easy fix for some things like vertical alignment and so forth, but really this is not one of them.

Comment: @Ennui I didn't say it was.

Comment: @A.R. my point is that falling back to using tables or table display values is usually a shortcoming of the coder and the code design not of the language itself.  Again though, arguably in this situation you can use tables and claim it's semantic.  The other main solution would essentially be building a CSS row/col fluid grid that behaves much like a table anyway!

Comment: @Ennui There are hundreds of things that CSS can't do (because of its shortcomings) that a table can.  Here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458993/left-align-text-and-right-align-image-in-css.  Also, end users don't care if it is a table or not, that is left to CSS fans.

Comment: @A.R. Vertical alignment of content with an unspecified / unpredictable height is the ONE example I gave so that doesn't lend a lot of strength to your 'hundreds of things' assertion. There are also a lot of upcoming / experimental layout modes (flexbox, css grid,  etc) in CSS that will make it a lot more powerful with respect to flow content and positioning elements.  Your average internet user might not care if it's a table or CSS, but screen readers, crawler bots / indexers and anything else that needs to scrape data or interpret your markup semantically does care.

Comment: @Ennui Upcoming tech and future blah blah blah is all well and good, but we live in the now.  Let's face it, CSS does a lot of things well, but layout isn't one of them.

Answer (score 4):

it should be enough to set a width to the labels that is larger than the largest label-text

example css

```
 label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:350px;
 }
```

so all inputs would line up after 350px, is that your desired effect ?
http://jsfiddle.net/dKjpk/5/

Comment: Doesn't `label` also need a `display:inline-block` ?

Comment: youre right it works just awesome, nevertheless i guess the best solution is to float labels left and float inputs right, like ravb79 stated

Comment: I mention this approach in the question.  Yeah, it works, but I'm really asking if there is a simpler, more change tolerant way.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option

```
ul {
  display: table;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

label, input {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Of course you should adapt the css to your specific form, but this gives you table **layout** without sacrificing the markup. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linorosa/VCKA9/)

Comment: Nice solution. Avoiding to use width attribute. It is good! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using floating inside the label if it's possible to give `ul` a fixed / relative width:

```
ul{
  width:500px; // or 100%;
}

li{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

li{
    list-style:none;
    clear:both;
}

li label{
    float:left;
}

li input{
    float:right;
}
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66NN9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Arguably you could justify using a table here, since semantically you can consider that form to be tabular data.

Otherwise you need to either float the `input` elements right within their container so they are all flush, set a fixed width on the `label` elements, or use some kind of fluid grid to handle this (I usually use Foundation so I would use columns for this, with both `label` and `input` elements set to `width: 100%` within their fluid containers).

Answer (score 0):

try it like this
by creating a table your things are in the same area beneath each other

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        label{
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="street">Street</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="street"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="suite">Suite</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="suite"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="city">City</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="city"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="state_region">State or Region</label></td>
                <td><select><option>Arizona</option></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="pc">Postal Code</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="country">Country</label></td>
                <td><select><option>USA</option></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="phone">Phone</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="phone"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="fax">Fax</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fax"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```