# Text left and image right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make text left and image right in the div. I found many examples in Stackoverflow where image is left and text right, then i tried to switch them but can't make it work.
I found [that on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458993/left-align-text-and-right-align-image-in-css) but doesn't make sense for me.

I've tried this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/judj5nw6/) but you'll see that it wont works.

```
.main-topic {
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 1541px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}

.left-text{
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.right-picture{
    float: right;
}

.right-picture > img{
    display: block;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

My goal is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsHXE.png) (sorry can't post image i haven't enough reputation). I want that text be left side on the bordered div and picture in the right side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `display: flex;` to `.main-topic` will do the trick.

And remove following css. There is no need of it now.

```
.right-picture{
    float: right;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/judj5nw6/3/)**

**Edit:**

If don't required static width and height then, remove static `height` from `section` and static `width` from `.main-topic` will make result better.

Which is `width: 1541px;` from `.main-topic` And `height: 500px;` from `section`

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/judj5nw6/5/)**

Comment: Hello ketan, unfortunately flex display have less browser support.

Comment: thanks but there's space between picture and div border. I want the text and picture to be directly surrounded by the border

Comment: @LevanTsivadze that's because you have lots of width in parent div and you have given fixed width to image. Is there  required. `width: 1541px;` to `.main-topic`

Comment: @UmerJaved flexbox support all latest browser. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: But it may not work if he's making the website for the mobiles too. Because android's pre installed browsers doesnt suppprt flexbox and everyone is not having latest mobiles.

Comment: @LevanTsivadze remove static static height from `section` and static width from `.main-topic` will do. https://jsfiddle.net/judj5nw6/5/

Comment: @UmerJaved as per your requirement. If don't want `display:flex` the use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` will work. https://jsfiddle.net/judj5nw6/7/

Answer (score 1):

Remove float:right from img and put float: left in .left-text

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

ul.topnav {
 list-style-type: none;
 /*position: fixed; */
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 400px;
 background-color: #110E0C;
   /*width: 100%;
   top: 0; */
}

ul.topnav li {
 float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 14px 30px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 /*background-color: #3F4345;*/
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
 background-color: #C8D0D7; 
 color: #D8610C;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #D8610C;
}

ul.topnav li a.active {
 background-color: #C8D0D7;
 color: #D8610C;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #D8610C;
}


header {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 2px;
 color:black;
 background-color: #C8D0D7;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}

header img {
 
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 margin-left: 900px; 
 float:left;
 
}
header p {
 padding: 40px;
}

section {
 background-color: #333333;
 height: 500px;
}

section img {
 border: 1px solid white;
 height: 400px;
 width: 500px;
}

section h3 {
 color: white;
}

section p {
 color: white;
 height: 170px;
 width: 600px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 20px;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.main-topic {
 border: 2px solid green;
 width: 1541px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 clear: both;
}

.left-text{
 vertical-align:middle;
  float:left;
}

.right-picture{

}

.right-picture > img{
 display: block;
}

.clear{
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
 <section>
  <div class="main-topic">
   <div class="left-text">
    <h3>Deadpool Fans Petition 'SNL' for Superhero to Host</h3>
    <p>
     Deadpool fans want its superhero to host Saturday Night Live — Deadpool, that is, not Ryan Reynolds. Fans of the Merc With a Mouth, who led the Marvel film to a history-making debut at the box office, have launched a Change.org petition calling for the antihero to host an upcoming episode of the NBC sketch comedy show. "We've all seen the trailers, the magazine covers, the viral videos, and the billboards by now, so what's left for Deadpool (Ryan Reynolds) to do?" creator Andrew Stege asks in the petition, which is directed to SNL, creator Lorne Michaels, parent.
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="right-picture">
    <img src="http://cdn3.whatculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/f5S3dvUb.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  <div>
 </section>
```

Comment: thanks but there's space between picture and div border

Answer (score 0):

How about this: http://jsbin.com/yenuxajode

Just float the text div left with width 50% (or whatever you want) and float the image div right with the remaining width. Make the img have max-width:100%; to keep it all on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/judj5nw6/6/), removed some height/width settings and adjusted the following CSS rules, so now it looks good

```
.main-topic {
    display: table;
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.left-text{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.right-picture{
    display: table-cell;
}
```