# JSON search results optimising

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to fix a site that has JSON data. It is property-related site and when I am searching for a property that is flat and click on search it is loading the properties that match this requirement. My question is, how can I make my css work?

```
output += "<p>" + data.properties[i].type + " $" + data.properties[i].price +"</p>" + data.properties[i].description+ "<a href=" + data.properties[i].url + "><img src=" + data.properties[i].picture + "></a>"; }
```

When I try to add a div or css rule it gives me an error.

Comment: You can use CSS to position the image or the text. But without knowing what you have we cannot really provide a solution. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: The title is completely misleading. JSON has nothing to do with what you're asking.

Comment: Now it's even worse. *"how can I make my css work?"* How should we know? You have not posted your CSS and have not explained what you want to achieve with your CSS. We can only help you if you provide us with information. If I asked you right now, how can I fix my door, would you be able to tell me precisely what I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you provide your error, as well as a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I am trying to print the results from the JSON file. I have filters etc. When printed, my results seems messy and I am trying to fix the picture on the left and the description on the right. Since it is in the <script></script> tags I do not know how to do this. I tried with `$("img").css` but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here for htlm5: [Left align text AND right align image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458993/left-align-text-and-right-align-image-in-css)

here for others: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_img_align.asp